# Spark Structured Streaming - writeStream split data hourly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-kinesis, spark-structured-streaming

Currently we have Spark streaming running in Production. I am in process of converting the code to use Structured streaming.
 I am able to successfully read data from Kinesis and write (sink) to Parquet file in S3 .

Our business logic demands, we write the streamed data in hourly folders. The incoming data from kinesis does not have any date-time field. So cannot partitionBy date-time.
 We have a defined a function `[getSubfolderNameFromDate()]` which gets us the current hour+date (1822062017 - 18th Hour of the day, 22nd June 2017) so we can write data in hourly folders.

With Spark streaming the Context gets re-initialized and automatically writes data in next hour folder, but I am not able to achieve the same with structured streaming.

For example, 2 million records were streamed in 4th hour of the day, it should be written to `"S3_location/0422062017.parquet/"`, data streamed in the following hour should be in `"S3_location/0522062017.parquet/"` so on and so forth.

With Structured streaming it continuous to write to same folder throughout the day, which I understand is because it evaluates the folder name just once and continuous to append the data to it.
 But I want to append new data to hourly folders, is there a way to achieve this ?

I am currently using below query :

```
 val query = streamedDataDF  
  .writeStream  
  .format("parquet")  
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDir)  
  .option("path", fileLocation  + FileDirectory.getSubfolderNameFromDate() + ".parquet/")  
  .outputMode("append")   
  .start()
```

Comment: Just partition your data by hours?

Comment: @zsxwing : partitionBy writes data like : s3araw://s3-location/**hour=0222062017**/part-00000--b414.gz.parquet

Whereas we are expecting it to be s3araw://s3-location/**0222062017**/part-00000--b414.gz.parquet

Comment: Or wait for Spark 2.2.0. Then you can use once trigger: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/22/running-streaming-jobs-day-10x-cost-savings.html

Comment: Add the current datetime to the streamed data and partition your data by that date.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. 
I tried @maxmithun suggestion and added  `date_format(current_timestamp(), "HHddMMyyyy").alias("date")` to readStream and used `partitionBy date` in writeStream and got the expected results.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit where to add the date_format as alias ?

Comment: How did you implement data partitioning with path that doesn't contain column names (/2018/01/29/data-file.gz.parguet)? Using partitionBy always puts a column name in a path (/<column-name>=<column-value>).